# Get number from list by int beginning

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to get all codes from list, where code starts with like 999, 88, and similar. I have:

```
public class CompCodes
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int code {get;set;}
}

public List<CompCodes> FunctionToGetBegginings(int codeBeggining){
   List<CompCodes> allcodes = ...... (all codes from db);
   var result = allcodes.Where(m=> m.code.Contains(codeBeggining) ).ToList();
   return result;
}
```

But I can't seem to get this working with Int, but with String i can.

```
**Given variables**:
Comp A, 11588842;
Comb B, 88856484;
Comp C, 88835454;

**Given codeBeggining**: 888;

**Expected result**: 
Comb B, 88856484;
Comp C, 88835454;
```

Comment: `int` doesn't have a method called `.Contains()`.  Did you mean to convert it to a `string` first?  `m.code.ToString().Contains(codeBeggining)` ?

Comment: try this => `var result = allcodes.Where(m=> m.code.ToString().StartsWith(codeBeggining) ).ToList();`

Comment: Well i hoped You can do search with ints, but i gues you can't. Thanks for reply, gonna change to string then do search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
 var result = allcodes.Where(m=> m.code.ToString().StartsWith(codeBeggining.ToString())).ToList();
```